# How to extract specific digits after underscore from filename in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, filenames

I have a number of file names like:

```
/home/abc/xyz/12345_993456_pqr
/home/abc/xyz/12345_883456_pqr
/home/abc/xyz/12345_773456_pqr
```

I need to extract the first two digits right after the first underscore i.e. `99` or `88` or `77`. It's not `99/88/77` always...just an example...I tried with:

```
re.search()
```

and

```
isdigit()
```

but its not working. Could anybody please help out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Step by step:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename('/home/abc/xyz/12345_993456_pqr')
'12345_993456_pqr'

>>> os.path.basename('/home/abc/xyz/12345_993456_pqr').split('_')
['12345', '993456', 'pqr']

>>> os.path.basename('/home/abc/xyz/12345_993456_pqr').split('_')[1]
'993456'

>>> os.path.basename('/home/abc/xyz/12345_993456_pqr').split('_')[1][:2]
'99'
```

Comment: could you please explain it a little? I am new to python...what is the "os.path.basename"?
i need to store the extracted digits in a variable...

Comment: Added the output of the intermediate steps.

Comment: [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.basename#os.path.basename_) gives the name of a file when a path (ie not just the file name) is provided.

Comment: @Mike Thanks a lot! Could you please suggest what to do if the filename is stored in a variable lets say       
'path = /home/abc/xyz/12345_993456_pqr'

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok this is quite tricky but try this:

```
import os, re
reg_exp = re.compile('_\d\d')
digits = [j[1:] for j in sum([reg_exp.findall(os.path.basename(i))[:1] 
                                              for i in filenames], [])]
```